# Can I use two <ul> in one <nav> tag?

Tags: html, tags

The title pretty much explains the question,  I need to know whether I can use two uls in one nav tag?

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I have seen this method even more complicated one in bootstrap navigation menu

Comment: Sure. You can use two UL in a nav. It could have multiple UL's if you wanted. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can have as many as you need. Have you tried it?

Comment: I have tried it. I need to know if there is no problem from the seo perspective

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use two ul in one nav.
For example, you may want to have two menus in a v